# Problem with p5.js rect border radius not working?

Tags: p5.js

I am working on a project in the p5.js library and I am trying to deal with the border radius elements of the rect() function.

The p5 reference lists this as the parameters of the function, with the last 4 option parameters dealing with their respective corners

```
rect(x, y, w, h, [tl], [tr], [br], [bl]);
```

The problem I'm having is that the code is ignoring the last two variables for the bottom-right and bottom-left corners.

```
rect(width/2, height/2, 200, 200, 40, 20, 0, 40);
```

This should be displaying a rectangle with different radii on each corner, but its ignoring the last two parameters.

I've looked online and some people had this problem a couple years ago and it was supposedly patched. However, I have the latest version of the library as of January 2020 and it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

It appears only projects generated from the command line are having this problem

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (0.10.2)

Comment: The code you send is perfectly running for me:
https://editor.p5js.org/darcane/sketches/OThzu1aEd